# write excel formula if in python

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, libraries

I'm trying to automate excel with python & there is some function for specific column in excel like this

> =IF(AND(AD2=0;AE2=0;AF2=0;AG2=0);"000-000";IF(AND(AE2=0;AF2=0;AG2=0);$AD$1;IF(AND(AF2=0;AG2=0);$AE$1;IF(AND(AG2=0);$AF$1;$AG$1))))

i need to put this formula for new column based on my dataframe like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'AD2':['0', '0', '163', '256'], 'AE2':['0', '0', '163', '236'], 'AF2':['0', '0', '163', '236'], 'AG2':['0', '139', '0', '415']})
```

is there any chance what kind of libraries that i need to use and example for that. Thank you

Comment: Did you inspect the Excel sheet? `AE2` refers to a cell, not a column. It checks the value of the AE (30th) column in the second row.

Comment: yes, i mean refer to excel sheet. I mean how to write that formula in python